# Derivative of complex matrix function which is based on LCMV

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives

My problem is based on beamforming.I want to minimize the power of $HW^HX$, which is signal sequence received at ***M*** recieve antennas. Meanwhile keep $ AW^H = 1$.  ***X*** is a signal sequence with T sampling points.
Here is the function.
$$\min_W tr[|HW^HX|^2] \\$$
$$\text{subject to} \ AW^H = 1$$
$$W \in \mathbb{C}^{1 \times N} \quad H \in \mathbb{C}^{M \times N} \quad X \in \mathbb{C}^{1 \times T} \quad A \in \mathbb{C}^{1 \times N}$$
***tr*** means trace of the matrix. ***H*** means conjugate transpose.
***H, X, A*** is determinant.

And the cost function based on Lagrange multiplier goes like,
$$J=tr[(HW^HX)(HW^HX)^H]+\lambda(AW^H -1)$$ 
So,my question is how to calculate $\frac{\partial\text{J}}{\partial W}$

Answer (score 2):

Column vectors look a bit more natural. To that end, define
$$\eqalign{
w = W^H,\quad a = A^H,\quad x = X^H \\
}$$
The constraint $a^Hw=1$ can be satisfied by constructing
$$\eqalign{
w &= \frac{a}{a^Ha} + \bigg(I-\frac{aa^H}{a^Ha}\bigg)y \;=\; b+Py\\
}$$
where y is an arbitrary (unconstrained) vector, $b$ is the conjugate transpose of the Moore-Penrose inverse of $a$, and $P$ is the projector into the nullspace of $a$.

It will also be convenient to define the following matrix (itself is a function of $y$)
$$M = Hwx^H$$
The cost function can be written as
$$J = \|M\|_F^2 \;=\; M^*:M$$
where $M^*$ denotes the complex conjugate and the colon is a convenient product notation for the trace, i.e.
$$B:C = {\rm Tr}(B^TC)$$
**NB:** The use of $B^T$ rather than $B^H$ is deliberate.

Properties of the trace allow a colon product to be rearranged in many equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
B:C &= C:B \\
B:CD &= C^TB:D \;=\; BD^T:C \\
}$$
Calculate the differential and gradient of $J$ with respect to the unconstrained $y$-variable.
$$\eqalign{
dJ &= M^*:dM \\
 &= M^*:H\,dw\,x^H \\
 &= H^TM^*x^*:dw \\
 &= (H^HMx)^*:P\,dy \\
 &= (PH^HMx)^*:dy \\
\frac{\partial J}{\partial y} &= (PH^HMx)^* \\
}$$
Set the gradient to zero and solve for the optimal value.
$$\eqalign{
PH^HMx&=\bigg(I-\frac{aa^H}{a^Ha}\bigg)H^H\big(Hwx^H\big)x\;={\tt\large 0}\\
H^HHw &= \bigg(\frac{aa^H}{a^Ha}\bigg)H^HHw \\
z &= \bigg(\frac{aa^H}{a^Ha}\bigg)z \quad\implies z = \{a,\,0\} \\
}$$
Set $z=\lambda a$ and solve for $w$ assuming $\,(H^HH)^{-1}$ exists
$$\eqalign{
H^HHw &= \lambda a \\
w &= \lambda (H^HH)^{-1}a
 \;=\; \frac{(H^HH)^{-1}a}{a^H(H^HH)^{-1}a} \\
}$$
After a lengthy calculation, this choice of $w$ results in
$$J = \frac{x^Hx}{a^H(H^HH)^{-1}a}$$
Alternatively, set $z=0$ and solve for $w$ assuming that $H^+H\ne I,\,$ 
$$\eqalign{
0 &= H^HHw \\
w &= \lambda(I-H^+H)p 
 \;=\; \frac{(I-H^+H)p}{a^H(I-H^+H)p} \\
}$$
where $H^+$ is the Moore-Penrose inverse and $p$ is an arbitrary vector.  This choice of $w$ results in a much simpler calculation
$$\eqalign{
&Hw = 0 \\
&M = (Hw)x^H = 0 \\
&J = \|M\|^2 = 0
}$$
which is the minimum possible value for a norm.

Note that these two results for the optimal $w$ vector are *mutually exclusive*, since if $(H^HH)^{-1}$ exists (as required by the first solution) then it can be used to calculate $H^+$ and falsify the assumption of the second solution, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
&H^+ = (H^HH)^{-1}H^H \\
&H^+H = (H^HH)^{-1}H^HH \;\equiv\; I \\
}$$

Comment: really thank for your answer and sorry for replying so late. 
your answer is trying to find the optimal value of the subset of ___J___ that I asked, and meanwhile satisfy  the constraint $a^Hw=1$, right? But it may not satisfy the $\frac{\partial\text{J}}{\partial W}$, where $J=tr[(HW^HX)(HW^HX)^H]+\lambda(AW^H -1)$,right?
If I didn't get your answer right,please let me know. 
And is there any chance that I can solve this partial derivative function directly and get a expression of ___W___ with determinant matrix?  I might ask stupid questions due to lack of math knowledge, and thank again!

Comment: I updated my answer a bit, but I'm not sure what you mean by _determinant_ since I don't see any determinant in your question. I see vertical bars, which are sometimes used to denote the determinant, but your Lagrangian clears up that ambiguity by expanding the expression into a matrix _norm_.

Comment: One more note:  By reformulating the problem as an _unconstrained_ optimization, there's no longer a need for the Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: very sorry! I said wrong, it's not determinant, what I really means it's can I get a ___W___ expressed by the function of known matrix(in this case, ___H___,___X___,___A___) by directly applying derivative of cost function. 
And I am studying your answer, thanks again!

Comment: To get an expression in terms of the original uppercase variables, just take the conjugate transpose of the lowercase expression, e.g. $$W = \frac{A(H^HH)^{-1}}{A(H^HH)^{-1}A^H}$$

Comment: really thanks! I think I need some time to absorb the answer.